# Bootstrap page rendering issue on Firefox Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, mobile

I have a div with a background image that is set to be the height of the viewport (height: 100vh), with an SVG image overlayed. Everything works fine on the desktop version of Firefox (resizing windows or using the mobile preview), but it wants to render the full image length on Firefox mobile.

The page is: http://sandy.utah.gov/_Adventureweek/index.html

Everything works fine in Chrome Mobile and Opera Mobile.

Also, peculiarly, if you select text farther down the page, the page suddenly decides to redraw and renders correctly on Firefox Mobile (all on my Samsung Galaxy S6, using current versions of the respective apps).

I've been trying to figure out what's going on, but I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: Sounds like a rendering engine issue my friend, I had a similar problem with safari and web video. Wasn't really anything that could be done.

Comment: Could be. The rendering behavior here certainly seems nonsensical to me. I've filed a bug report with Mozilla, since they're the only ones who can fix it if that's the case.

Comment: Id browser sniff and see if you couldn't disable the problematic portion.